# Like Box ('Could not retrieve the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in.')

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I need some information, why like box frame not working: 'Could not retrieve the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in.'. I`m testing this href in http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug - it says correct answer, but frame not working.

In access logs for UA facebookexternalhit/1.1 always answer status 200 (and 301/302 for specific page).

example page: http://www.now.ru/item/series/comedy/Univer_222394

additional information: on some pages frame works, and some does not work

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Facebook Like Box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) is really designed to use the URL for a Facebook page, not for a general Web Page.  It pulls Timeline content from a fan page within Facebook.

It can be used for a Web Page if the page has defined Open Graph Meta Tags and has been Liked at least once.  However, there will be no "stream" functionality.  The Like-Box for a Web Page would just have functionality similar to the Facepile plugin (except that Facepile just shows you friends, and a Like-Box also shows non-friends.)

Typically, though, you would want to supply the Like-Box with a Facebook Page URL in the following format:

```
http://www.facebook.com/pages/Facebook-Page-Name/Facebook-Page-ID
```

Perhaps you are intending to use a Like Button or Facepile [Social Plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/) instead?  Either of those can accept any URL as input.

Comment: hmm... im confused because on this page its work :)
http://www.now.ru/item/movies/Rossiyskoye/Zolushka_254827
but href not FB page.
but thanks! im try asking a developer

Comment: The Like-Box doesn't appear to be loading on that page either.  What are you trying to do?  The Like-Box is used to pull a history of posts from a Facebook page.

Comment: found that the widget works with any link, provided that the link liked with widget <fb:like>. But is unstable ... and sorry :) but maybe support FB help me...

Comment: If you add Open Graph meta tags to the page and then Like it should work:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/  It just won't have a "Stream."

Comment: Open Graph meta tags used. but the widget doesn't always work

Comment: minimum width must be 292px...I have same problem now